# How to show java object returned in JSONArray in html page

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json

I'm a beginner in jquery and ajax, I have downloaded an example to customize but I ran into a problem.
I have a java class named Time with these fields :

```
String start;
String end;
ClassRoom class1;
ClassRoom class2;
ClassRoom class3;
ClassRoom class4;
```

Note that the ClassRoom class also has it's own fields,TeacherName,Grade,...

An array containing Time class objects will be sent to the below code by a servlet as a JSONArray, The point is here, I want to show the fields of class1,class2,class3, in the html page, is this possible?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#odddays").click(function(event){
           $.get('ClassesInformationGetter',function(responseJson) {
            if(responseJson!=null){
                $("#oddDaysClassBoard").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                var table1 = $("#oddDaysClassBoard");
                $.each(responseJson, function(key,value) { 
                     var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
                     rowNew.children().eq(0).text(value['start']+value['end']); 
                     rowNew.children().eq(1).text(value['class1']); 
                     rowNew.children().eq(2).text(value['class2']); 
                     rowNew.children().eq(3).text(value['class3']); 
                     rowNew.children().eq(4).text(value['class4']); 
                     rowNew.children().eq(5).text(value['class5']); 
                     rowNew.children().eq(6).text(value['class6']); 
                     rowNew.children().eq(7).text(value['class7']); 
                     rowNew.children().eq(8).text(value['class8']); 
                        rowNew.appendTo(table1);
                });
                }
            });
  });      
});
</script>
```

Comment: what did you get inside function,console.log(responseJson);?

Comment: I have no idea about Json or jquery or ajax, I said I'm a beginner, But if you want to know what I have in the output,well,In my html page I get [Object object] as the value of  "value['class1']"